# An abstract class inheriting an interface, how to implement explicit interface?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, inheritance, interface

I have created two interfaces *I1* and *I2*. I have inherited those two interfaces to an abstract class.
The interfaces *I1* and *I2* has the same method *Add()*, How to implement this in the derived class using explicit interface?

**Code Snippet**:

```
using System;

interface I1
{
    void Add(int _fn, int _sn);
    void Prod(int _fn, int _sn);
    void Sub(int _fn, int _sn);
}

interface I2
{
    void Add(int _fn, int _sn);
}

abstract class Simple: I2, I1
{
    public abstract void Add(int _fn, int _sn);
    public abstract void Prod(int _fn, int _sn);
    public abstract void Sub(int _fn, int _sn);
    void I2.Add(int _fn, int _sn);
}


class Program : Simple
{
    public override void Add(int _fn, int _sn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_fn+_sn);
    }

    public override void Prod(int _fn, int _sn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_fn * _sn);
    }

    public override void Sub(int _fn, int _sn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_fn - _sn);
    }

    void Add(int _fn, int _sn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_fn % _sn);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        I1 inter = new Program();

        inter.Add(2, 3);
        inter.Prod(2, 4);
        inter.Sub(3,5);
    }
}
```

I am getting **an error**:

```
Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Add' with the same parameter types
```

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't any point in using *two* Add() methods that do the exact same thing.  The abstract Simple.Add() already implements both I1.Add and I2.Add.  So just get rid of the explicit interface implementation and the unneeded Program.Add().  And write proper code, an abstract method cannot have a body.

Comment: I have edited my code to give you a better picture of what I want.

Comment: If you add body to Add in abstract Simple class the code compiles fine. Without the error you've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an abstract method with a different name:

```
abstract class Simple: I2, I1
{
    public abstract void Add(int _fn, int _sn);
    public abstract void Prod(int _fn, int _sn);
    public abstract void Sub(int _fn, int _sn);
    void I2.Add(int _fn, int _sn)
    {
        AddInternal(_fn, _sn);
    }

    protected abstract void AddInternal(int _fn, int _sn);
}
```

And override it in the concrete class:

```
protected override void AddInternal(int _fn, int _sn)
{
    Console.WriteLine(_fn + _sn);
}
```

Comment: Where is the implementation of AddInternal?  It just isn't needed.

Comment: @arun, this works for me: https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/735f852c2a396bd7a639